# c3 donut chart label with line connector

Tags: c3.js

I am using `c3 donut` chart. I want to display customized label. Like show `label`outside of arc with line pointing. Please see image.

[image: Donut chart label with line]

Is there any way to display label with line outside of arc?

I have done lot of research but not able to find a solution.

Comment: AFAIK you have to do that with D3.js and it's not easy. There are alternative libraries which can do that in a easy way

Comment: @beaver thanks, can you please suggest any open source library?

Comment: You could use highcharts: see my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/e9c0rLoe/

Comment: Another example uses chart.js with an extension: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/0vrs58dc/

Comment: @beaver We can also use d3pie.js: see my codepen: https://s.codepen.io/jignesh2290/debug/bLGBor/VJkxxZQdVjqk

Comment: d3pie.js has not great support: see https://github.com/benkeen/d3pie, highcharts and chart.js have many developers working on them and good documentation

Answer (score 0):

Another option seems to be to not show the percentages in the donut part of the chart.

One can instead put the percentages down onto the labels. So, instead of:

- Category 1
- Category 2
- Category 3

it would say:

- Category 1: 19%
- Category 2: 5%
- Category 3: 13%

Would this work? Is this possible? I see that I can change the label text as I fill the columns array, but what I have at that point is the number of things, not the percentages. I would have to calculate the percentages myself in the columns list setup code. I could do this, but ick.

Any other options?